# Jenkins checkstyle.xml doesn't match anything: 'build' exists but not 'build/logs/checkstyle.xml

Tags: php, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins so please forgive me if this sounds silly.

I cannot seem to get checkstyle running in Jenkins, I have set up the build file and added the required information (below) but it will not pick up the file.

The error I get is:
'build/logs/checkstyle.xml' doesn't match anything: 'build' exists but not 'build/logs/checkstyle.xml'

```
<target name="phpcs" description="Generate checkstyle.xml using PHP_CodeSniffer">
  <exec executable="phpcs" output="/dev/null">
   <arg value="--report=checkstyle" />
   <arg value="--report-file=${basedir}/build/logs/checkstyle.xml" />
   <arg value="--standard=${basedir}/build/phpcs.xml" />
   <arg value="--patterns=${source}/Plugin/Purifier/Vendor/" />
   <arg path="${source}" />
  </exec>
</target>
```

Error from Command line

```
phpcs:
 [exec] Result: 2
```

phpcs.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Sebastian">
    <description>Sebastian Bergmann's coding standard</description>
    <rule ref="Generic.PHP.DisallowShortOpenTag"/>
    <rule ref="Generic.PHP.NoSilencedErrors"/>
</ruleset>
```

Reported Error:

Errors
No report files were found. Configuration error?

UPDATE

---

Error I have resolved the above error and am now getting the following:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php on line 1389
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpcs:0
PHP   2. PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->process() /usr/bin/phpcs:37
PHP   3. PHP_CodeSniffer->process() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/CLI.php:545
PHP   4. PHP_CodeSniffer->processFile() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:496
PHP   5. PHP_CodeSniffer->_processFile() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:1209
PHP   6. PHP_CodeSniffer_File->start() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer.php:1331
PHP   7. PHP_CodeSniffer_File->_parse() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:382
PHP   8. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::tokenizeString() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:586
PHP   9. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_createScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:956
PHP  10. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1344
PHP  11. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  12. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  13. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  14. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  15. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  16. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  17. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  18. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  19. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  20. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  21. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  22. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  23. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  24. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  25. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  26. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  27. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  28. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  29. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  30. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  31. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  32. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  33. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  34. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  35. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  36. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  37. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  38. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  39. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  40. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  41. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  42. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  43. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  44. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  45. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  46. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  47. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  48. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  49. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  50. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  51. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  52. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  53. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  54. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  55. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  56. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  57. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  58. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  59. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  60. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  61. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  62. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  63. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  64. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  65. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  66. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  67. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  68. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  69. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  70. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  71. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  72. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  73. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  74. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  75. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  76. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  77. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  78. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  79. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  80. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  81. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  82. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  83. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  84. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  85. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  86. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  87. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  88. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  89. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  90. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  91. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  92. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  93. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  94. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  95. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  96. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  97. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  98. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
PHP  99. PHP_CodeSniffer_File::_recurseScopeMap() /usr/share/php/PHP/CodeSniffer/File.php:1480
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, have you output the commandline and run it manually? Does it run? Is there an error? Don't you think it's not that clever to log to /dev/null ;) ?

Comment: Hi Hakra,

Thanks for your quick response!

Yes it builds successfully, and all other parts work correctly, I have set it up to build when I commit to a git repository, I have also updated the output to:

    ${basedir}/build/logs/jdepend.xml

Unfortunately the error still appears in the configuration :S

Comment: No, I did not talk about the rest of your build. I just wrote about the one part that fails: the phpcs commandline call. What is the commandline of that one part that is fired against the system? Please output it, add it to your question, run it actually on the build system, paste it's output as well. Show the error messages. Tell us whether or not manual operation creates the XML file and so on and so forth. Just do it manually what Jenkins would do automated. Just putting all (useful) output into dev/null is not helpful if you debug things ;).

Comment: Ah I see, I have added it to the question.

Comment: Well the actual commandline is missing. And it looks like you never executed it manually, right? I just point you to that because the returncode 2 for example can mean that the usage-information is shown which is the case when you mixed some arguments or when you did pass parameters in a wrong format and such. I'll add a list as an answer which more or less is a comment only.

Comment: The recursion depth limit error is a xdebug setting. You *might* need to raise it, code style checks can need recursion more than 100 depth:  http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level - also if those errors are the output, better log them instead of outputting them. That can be done by changing the php error configuration: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PHPCS returns with an exit-code of 2, it can have many reasons, unless you validate against output (outputting to `/dev/null` effectively prevents output [naturally])

- ERROR: PHP_CodeSniffer requires PHP version 5.1.2 or greater.
- ERROR: PHP_CodeSniffer requires the tokenizer extension to be enabled.
- ERROR: Could not locate .git directory (git)
- ERROR: Could not execute (git, svn, hg)
- ERROR: Could not locate .hg directory (hg)

Next to an error, it can be an error with parameters, you then see the usage description. I highly suggest you check the actual output as you know you've got exit code 2.

The listing was obtained with:

```
$ grep -rn -B 1 'exit(2);' *
```

which results for some slightly outdated phpcs version (1.3.3, 1.3.6 is stable right now):

```
CLI.php-66-            echo 'ERROR: PHP_CodeSniffer requires PHP version 5.1.2 or greater.'.PHP_EOL;
CLI.php:67:            exit(2);
--
CLI.php-71-            echo 'ERROR: PHP_CodeSniffer requires the tokenizer extension to be enabled.'.PHP_EOL;
CLI.php:72:            exit(2);
--
CLI.php-340-                    $this->printUsage();
CLI.php:341:                    exit(2);
--
CLI.php-347-                    $this->printUsage();
CLI.php:348:                    exit(2);
--
CLI.php-389-                    echo 'ERROR: Report type "'.$report.'" not known.'.PHP_EOL;
CLI.php:390:                    exit(2);
--
CLI.php-447-            $this->printUsage();
CLI.php:448:            exit(2);
--
CLI.php-454-            $this->printUsage();
CLI.php:455:            exit(2);
--
CLI.php-499-                $this->printUsage();
CLI.php:500:                exit(2);
--
CLI.php-509-            $this->printInstalledStandards();
CLI.php:510:            exit(2);
--
Reports/Gitblame.php-105-            echo 'ERROR: Could not locate .git directory '.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
Reports/Gitblame.php:106:            exit(2);
--
Reports/Gitblame.php-112-            echo 'ERROR: Could not execute "'.$command.'"'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
Reports/Gitblame.php:113:            exit(2);
--
Reports/Hgblame.php-106-            echo 'ERROR: Could not locate .hg directory '.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
Reports/Hgblame.php:107:            exit(2);
--
Reports/Hgblame.php-113-            echo 'ERROR: Could not execute "'.$command.'"'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
Reports/Hgblame.php:114:            exit(2);
--
Reports/Svnblame.php-80-            echo 'ERROR: Could not execute "'.$command.'"'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
Reports/Svnblame.php:81:            exit(2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have managed to get the checkstyle result, hopefully with this someone can point me in the right direction: